# ¿Cómo ejecutar método al cerrar aplicación y no al minimizar?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación multiplataforma en Xamarin.Forms. Necesito realizar una serie de acciones en caso de que el usuario cierre la aplicación de forma definitiva.

El problema viene de que cuando se cierra o minimiza la aplicación siempre se accede al método OnSleep del fichero App.xaml.cs:

```
    protected override void OnSleep ()
    {
        // Handle when your app sleeps

    }
```

Pero yo necesito algún método al que se acceda solo y exclusivamente si el paciente cierra la app definitivamente en cualquiera de las plataformas de UWP, Android o iOs.

Alguien se ha enfrentado a este problema?

Comment: No hay un metodo onClose?

Comment: me temo que no, o no veo donde

Comment: Pudiste resolverlo,ando atorado en lo mismo